# how to write this in sql query to linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my `sql query`.

```
 select category from category where id in(select cid from subcategory)
```

I want to write this in `linq`. how can I write this .

there is sample which i know , but this I'm unable to write this for my requirement

```
from n in objvar
               where new[] { "Amit", "Kumar", "XYZ" }.Contains(n.hello)
               select n
```

Comment: please make an attempt.

Comment: What is `subcategory`?

Comment: @Gabe: subcategory is another table which contain cid column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution would be

```
 var res= from c in Category
                    join
                        s in SubCategory on c.id equals s.cid
                    select c;
```

Comment: i didn't get you what you are doing . but this gave me idea to do this. thanks for your hep. +1 for you.